# pypy sandbox can't import time, import site fails

Tags: python, sandbox, pypy

I've run the rpython translate to create a pypy sandbox.

```
~/pypy-2.3.1-linux64/bin/pypy ../../rpython/bin/rpython -O2 --sandbox targetpypystandalone
```

There are a few warnings, two which seem to involve time.

> ```
> [sandbox:WARNING] Not Implemented: sandboxing for external function 'clock_gettime'
> [sandbox:WARNING] Not Implemented: sandboxing for external function 'clock_getres'
> ```

The long and short of it is while the translate finishes, the following output occurs when I run the sandbox:

```
'import site' failed
Python 2.7.6 (32f35069a16d819b58c1b6efb17c44e3e53397b2, Jun 11 2014, 19:06:04)
[PyPy 2.3.1 with GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>>
```

And then import time fails as well:

```
>>>> import time
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named time
>>>>
```

Is this expected behavior for the sandbox? 
If so, what's the proper practice to embed site-packages and the like within a sandboxed process? 
I was hoping to use pip to install in that env, but the sandboxing seems to make it very difficult. (basically I run up against import time when I attempt to install distribute.py, as it requires datetime which requires time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just went through the same issue. The solution is to include `time` module when building the `pypy-c` sandbox. In [these instructions](http://pypy.org/download.html#building-from-source), add `--withmod-time` when building:

```
pypy ../../rpython/bin/rpython -O2 --sandbox targetpypystandalone --withmod-time
```

Other possible flags are listed here: http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/commandline.html